# Q: When using the Matlab fill function twice, areas get blank again

Tags: matlab, gps, fill

I have GPS data from 2 GPS antennas, recorded while moving, and I want to fill the area in between them for better illustration. These areas I want to fill overlap quite often. And sometimes after a second, or third, use of the fill function in the same area, the area gets blank again. I load parts of the data separately, since it is too much to store at once ([here is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WMia.png)).

Do you guys know how i can prevent that from happening?

```
for k=1:Nr 

if k<10
    A=load([PathName,'/Profile00',num2str(k),'_A.asc']);
    B=load([PathName,'/Profile00',num2str(k),'_B.asc']);
else
    A=load([PathName,'/Profile0',num2str(k),'_A.asc']);
    B=load([PathName,'/Profile0',num2str(k),'_B.asc']);
end

plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'b') % Plot GPS Tracks
plot(B(:,1),B(:,2),'b') % Plot GPS Tracks
PV1=[A(:,1);flipud(B(:,1));A(1,1)]; % Polygon Boundaries
PV2=[A(:,2);flipud(B(:,2));A(1,2)]; % Polygon Boundaries
h1=fill(PV1,PV2,'g');
set(h1,'EdgeColor','None');
set(h1,'facealpha',.5)
grid on
end
```